# Limit selection to visible doesn't work properly

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, opengl

I made a realistic aborygen bust portrait and wanted to make an *OpenGL viewport render* of it. But when I zoom out from the object the wireframe of the eyeball is getting more and more visible.
[image]

I want to make a render from a distance, but the further I zoom out from the model, the more eyeball's wireframe is visible. 
[image]
[image]

I have the ***Limit selection to visible*** enabled, but still the wireframe fragments of the eyeball are visible. I want to make the *OpenGL* render of the model without the wireframes overlapping. How to do it? Is there a setting I am missing?
[image]

Comment: That could be cliping problem. As you're going to do OpenGL render try to change clipping in the viewport.

Comment: Thanks man :). It did the job! I use Blender for so long and I'm still a dumb :O. Thnx once more!